# How to get data with respect to Month and Year

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I have core data with Entity @"Collection" with attributes payment, date etc and i stored "date"
with respect to date,month,year like "dd-MM-yyyy" but i want to fetch data with respect to only Month and Year so for this purpose what NSPredicate i use. If any one known this then kinldy guide me.

Comment: Use the correct data type.  `NSDate` is the correct type, not `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

As Droppy commented use `NSDate` as the field type.

If that is not possible you can fetch the rows you are interested in by using a `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE[cd] %@", kDateFieldKey, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*-%02d-%d", month, year]];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
```

where kDateFieldKey is the key for your date field ("date"), month is an integer representing the month and year is an integer representing the year.

Comment: this is not get the data which i want :(

Comment: What data do you want?

Comment: A predicate which fetch the data on the basis of Month and year. When i store data in data base then i am using dateFormatter 
"dd-MM-yyyy". While i want to fetch data with respect to only month and year not on the base of date.